# Independent, Uniform, Random Variable:

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Working on this:

> Alice and Bob agree to meet in the Copper Kettle after their Saturday
>   lectures. They arrive at times that are independent and uniformly
>   distributed between 12:00 and 13:00. Each is prepared to wait s
>   minutes before leaving. Find a minimal s such that the probability
>   that they meet is at least 25%.

I honestly can't figure out how to approach this one... It seems super simple, but I just can't wrap my head around it right now. Any advice on how to start?

Thank you.

Comment: This type of question has been asked and solved in great detail repeatedly on this forum.  Look around a bit.

Comment: @gfppaste: I hope you locate it, for a picture really helps, and someone will have drawn one. Let's measure time of wait in **hours**, can go to minutes later. Let $X$ be Alice's arrival time, $Y$ Bob's. We want $P(|X-Y|\le w)\ge 0.25$. The joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is $1$ on the square with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,1)$. what is the area of the region $|x-y|\le w$? Hint: Draw the line $x-y=w$ and $x-y=-w$.

Answer (score 1):

We can define Alice's arrival time by a and Bob's arrival time by b, with both a and b between uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. We can therefore define a set $C = \{(a,b): |a-b| \le \frac{s}{60}\}$. You should be able to graph this and see that it is a diagonal strip around the graph of y=x. The area outside of this strip is $(1-\frac{s}{60})^2$, so the area inside the strip is $1-(1-\frac{s}{60})^2$. We want this to be at least 0.25. From here, it is relatively straightforward to see what the minimum value of s should be.